# Finding the equation of the remaining hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, affine-geometry

This is a vector algebra question I'm struggling with--- it's low dimensional, but I still can't visualize 4D in the same way I can lower dimensions. It's also a toy problem for a harder version, but I figure I should try to understand a smaller version first.

I have the following line:

$$\ell(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$$

in $\mathbb{R}^4$, and two hyperplanes:

$$H_1 = \left\{ x : \sum_{i=1}^4 x_i = 2\right\} \text{ and } H_2 = \{ x : x_1 + x_2 = 1\}$$

The line is a $1$-dimensonal affine subspace, and lies on both $H_1$ and $H_2$. Moreover, $H_2 \neq H_1$, so $H_1 \cap H_2$ forms a $2$-dimensional affine subspace. What I seek is some $H_3$, preferably in "standard form" $\{x : \langle n, x \rangle =1 \}$ so that $\ell(\mathbb{R}) = H_1 \cap H_2 \cap H_3$.

Can someone give a **hint** on how to solve this problem?

EDIT:

Nevermind. I found it: $\{x : x_2 + x_3 = 0\}$.

Comment: You could consider a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ whose matrix w.r.t. the standard basis is given by $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&0&0\\ a&b&c&d\end{pmatrix}$$ Pick $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\text{rank}(A)=3$ and $a-b+c-d=0$. If you set $$W_3=\{(x,y,z,w)^T:ax+by+cz+dw=0\}$$ then taking $$H_3=W_3+(0,1,0,1)^T$$ will work.

Answer (score 1):

The given line is of the form $p = v_0 + t v_1$.  Hyperplanes on which this line exists are of the form $a^T (p - v_0) = 0 $, so you want to solve

$ v_1^T x = 0 $

This results in the orthogonal subspace to $v_1$.  Thus the vector $a$  is given by

$a = r u_1 + s u_2 + t u_3 $

Direct solution of $[1, -1, 1, -1] x = 0$ leads to

$u_1 = [1, 1, 0, 0], u_2 = [-1, 0, 1, 0], u_3 = [1, 0, 0, 1]$

$H_1$ corresponds to $u_1 + u_2 + u_3$, while $H_2$ corresponds to $u_1$.  You can construct $H_3$ by setting different (not all zero) combinations of $r,s,t$.